# No parameterless constructor defined for this object - Hangfire scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduler, hangfire

I've just installed Hangfire package in my MVC website.
I've created a Startup class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Website.Startup))]

namespace Website
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Hangfire.ConfigureHangfire(app);
            Hangfire.InitializeJobs();
        }
    }
}
```

and a Hangfire class

```
public class Hangfire
{
    public static void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
            config.UseServer();
            config.UseAuthorizationFilters(); 
        });
    }

    public static void InitializeJobs()
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<CurrencyRatesJob>(j => j.Execute(), "* * * * *");
    }
}
```

Also, I've created a new job in a separate class library

```
public class CurrencyRatesJob
{
    private readonly IBudgetsRepository budgetsRepository;

    public CurrencyRatesJob(IBudgetsRepository budgetsRepository)
    {
        this.budgetsRepository = budgetsRepository;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            var budgets = new BudgetsDTO();
            var user = new UserDTO();

            budgets.Sum = 1;
            budgets.Name = "Hangfire";
            user.Email = "email@g.com";

            budgetsRepository.InsertBudget(budgets, user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.ToString();
            throw new NotImplementedException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run the application, in the Hangfire's dashboard I get the following error:

```
Failed An exception occurred during job activation.
System.MissingMethodException

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Hangfire.JobActivator.ActivateJob(Type jobType)
   at Hangfire.Common.Job.Activate(JobActivator activator)
```

So, I'm a little lost here. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the register code where hangfire gets notified of what classes it should be using?

Comment: I think I don't have it. I don't remember reading about that. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Well I'm not a hangfire expert, but it's clear it's trying to resolve the `CurrencyRatesJob` but it can't because it doesn't know what `IBudgetsRepository` should be resolved to. That is why you are getting the no empty constructor error. Maybe this post can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615794/hangfire-autofac-with-mvc-app-injection-fails.

Comment: @MarianEne Check my response below, this takes care of injecting dependencies and the issues you already have.

Answer (score 5):

It appears you have not connected Hangfire to the IoC container you are using and therefore it uses its default strategy to create a requested type, which in your specific example means calling:

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CurrencyRatesJob));
```

Because the `CurrencyRatesJob` class does not have a default parameterless constructor, this fails with the error message you show in your question.

To connect Hangfire to your IoC infrastructure, you need to create your own `JobActivator` class that overrides the `ActivateJob` method and uses the configured IoC container to create instances of the requested job types.

An example that uses Unity as the container (`UnityJobActivator`) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28034217/2573395) and an example for the `Funq` container (`FunqJobActivator`) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775039/2573395).

The process is described in the [Hangfire documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html), and standard implementations for several container types are available from the [Hangfire github repo](https://github.com/HangfireIO)

Comment: Well, I'm using Ninject and I've seen that there is a Nuget package (Hangfire.Ninject), but I'm not sure how to work with it. I tried creating a parameterless constructor in the job and it was executed, but I didn't have the IBudgetsRepository object.

Comment: @MarianEne, right, because that is what you need the IoC for, to resolve the `IBudgetsRepository` dependency as the instance injected into your `CurrencyRatesJob`. Using that Nuget package, you would use the `UseNinjectActivator` extension method at startup: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);` with `kernel` being the instance of your Ninject kernel.

Comment: so I'm a little confused about where should I add this: `var kernel = new StandardKernel(); GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);`. If I add it to Global.asax I get a `Ninject.ActivationException`; if I add it to the job, right after the `try` I get the same parateterless exception.

Comment: @MarianEne, you mentioned you are already using Ninject in your project, so I would assume a `kernel` instance is already created in your MVC project startup code. If you are using the 'NinjectMvc' Nuget package, you should find a `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file in your `App_Start` folder. In its `private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)` method, add the line `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);`

Comment: So, I've renamed the class where I have the Hangfire configuration, from Hangfire to HangfireConfig, because there were some conflicts when I wanted to use UseNinjectActivator.

Then I moved `Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);` to my `NinjectWebCommon` class, where I have the kernel and I use it for binding the interfaces to the appropriate classes.

Now I get another error saying that `Hangfire.IGlobalConfiguration` does not contain a definition of `UseNinjectActivator`.

Comment: Have you added the line `using Hangfire;` to the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file?

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty straightforward discussion here: [Hangfire Discussion](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/hangfire-needs-parameterless-constructor/645)

I will include my sample code:

```
public class Job : IJob
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    private readonly IDbContext _context;

    public Job()
    {
         // this needs to be here, although this won't be used in the actual running
    }

    public Job(IService service, IDbContext context) : this()
    {
        _service = service;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void Run(SomeModel searchLocationModel)
    {
    }
}
```

My actual invoke of Hangfire is below:

```
IJob job = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.TryGet<Job>();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(job.ToString(), () => job.Run(model), Cron.Weekly, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the dependencies to get this working.
Install nuget unity package :

```
Install-Package Hangfire.Unity
```

And then register on Global.asax you will have BootStraper initialise method.Navigate to boot strapper class and in initialise  have following  code,

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Complete code will look something like following if you are using Unity.

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
     }



 private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
 {
    var container = new UnityContainer();       
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseUnityActivator(container);
    RegisterTypes(container);
    return container;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above answers were possible to implement in our project. So we ended up creating a background job helper that used reflection to instantiate the class (without a parameterless constructor) and then calling the method.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public static class BackgroundJobHelper
{
    public static object Execute(string userId, Type classType, string functionName, object[] param)
    {
        ServiceFactory serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory(userId);
        var classToInvoke = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { serviceFactory });
        return Send(classType, classToInvoke, functionName, param);
    }

    private static object Send(Type classType, object className, string functionName, object[] param, Type[] fnParameterTypes = null)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo;
        if (!fnParameterTypes.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(functionName, fnParameterTypes);
        }
        else
        {
            methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(functionName);
        }
        var methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        //Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'. While deserializing int is converted into long hence explictly make it Int32.
        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            var methodParameterType = methodParameters[i].ParameterType;
            if (param[i] != null)
            {
                if (param[i] is long l)
                {
                    if (l >= int.MinValue && l <= int.MaxValue) param[i] = (int)l;
                }
                else if (param[i].GetType() == typeof(JObject))
                {
                    param[i] = (param[i] as JObject).ToObject(methodParameterType);
                }
                else if (param[i].GetType() == typeof(JArray))
                {
                    param[i] = (param[i] as JArray).ToObject(methodParameterType);
                }
            }
        }
        return methodInfo.Invoke(className, param);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var backgroundJob = new BackgroundJobClient(new SqlServerStorage(db.Database.Connection));
var result = backgroundJob.Schedule(() => BackgroundJobHelper.Execute(userId, this.GetType(), nameof(this.SendMailAsync), new object[] { projectId, remarks }), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```